# How to rename result set of COUNT(*) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We were asked to create a SQL statement to show the count of customers whose country is USA. The column name of the result set should then be renamed into `numcustomers`.

The database is in here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all.

I already found the count(*) of customers in the USA:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'Germany'
```

But I can't figure out how to rename `COUNT(*)` into `numcustomers`. Any help?

Comment: Your current query does not involve `count(*)`.

Comment: And your current query doesn't return the customers in the USA - but those in Germany .....

Comment: can i know reason for down vote?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) AS numcustomers FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'USA'
```

Use `AS` keyword to set column alias.

Comment: or "SELECT count(*) numcustomers", or "SELECT numcustomers = count(*)" :)   (star was removed by SO)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUMCUSTOMERS FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE COUNTRY = 'USA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Akshey Bhat is right

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS numcustomers 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'USA'
```

This query to get a number of usa customer and this index name is numcustomers or column name is numcustomers

Answer (score 0):

As, there are many ways that we can address the above requirement, one is as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [numcustomers] 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'USA'
```